# Showing the slope of a line is a rational number with denominator $2$.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I am looking at Stark's 'An Introduction to Number theory' book, and I'm trying to do the following question from the exercises 7.1:

$Q4$: Show that if there are two different integral points with $x$-coordinate $1$ equally close to the line $y=\alpha x$ then $\alpha$ is a rational number with denominator $2$.

I think I have a solution, just looking for someone to run it by. This is a rough sketch I did in ms paint.

[image]

Comment: Will do thanks.

Comment: @martini I have to wait two days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the two points equally close to the line $(1,p_1)$ and $(1,p_2)$, with $p_2>p_1$, $\;p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb{N}$. From the question we have that the perpendicular distances to the line are equal. Consider the two triangles in the diagram. Each triangle has a right angle and both have another equal angle in common since they are opposite. Therefore all three angles are equal. Since they also have one side with the same length $d$ in common also, they are congruent ($ASA$).

Considering the lengths of the sides along the line $x=1$, we have $p2-\alpha=\alpha-p_1$ as the point $(1,\alpha)$ is the point of intersection of the two lines.

Thus $\alpha=\frac{p_1+p_2}{2}$, $\alpha$ is rational with denominator $2$.